# Applying rules to multiple classes using a * match

Tags: css, css-selectors

My class names generate dynamically and I'm trying to apply styling to them using a kind of preg_match. Is something like this possible?

```
<style>
    .*_class {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>

<div id="a_class">a</div>
<div id="b_class">b</div>
<div id="c_class">c</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use attribute selectors for this.

```
[id$="_class"] {

}
```

The above says, anything with an `id` that ends with `_class` should be selected. For more information, see [attribute selectors at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: Just note that attribute selectors are much less efficient than native class selectors.

Comment: The selector should actually target the attribute `id` not `class`, according to the presented markup. `[id$="_class"]`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps reconsider how your classes are generated. While [Praveen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40731421/4665) will work and directly answers the question, attribute selectors can be inefficient. You might want to consider leveraging the fact you can have more than one class per element. E.g.

```css
.class {color:#F00;}
.a.class {font-weight:bold; font-size:2em;}
```

```html
<div class="a class">a</div>
<div class="b class">b</div>
<div class="c class">c</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in control of the class names. I'm only able to change the CSS.

Comment: Selector inefficiency is only a constraint to worry about if you are building a website at a scale of Amazon or Facebook in terms of complexity and page loads. Probably the top 5% of sites by web traffic really benefit from such a concern.